# First push on modal navigation stack not animating

Tags: swiftui

I have a bug where I'm presenting a `NavigationStack` modally (`.sheet(...)`) and where the first view pushed onto the stack fails to animate. But if I then push more views or pop back, it animates as expected. It appears to be related to having the path of the stack `@Publish`ed in the view model because if I have the path as a `@State` property in the view it works just fine.

In this gif you can see that when View2 appears for the first time it doesn't animate, whereas subsequently it does.

[image]

Here's the code that generated the above gif, I'd be interested it anyone has encountered this and has a solution that keeps the path in the view model.

```swift
//
// Copyright © Derek Clarkson. All rights reserved.
//

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var showModal = false

    var body: some View {
        Button("Show modal") {
            showModal = true
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showModal) {
            View1(viewModel: ViewModel())
        }
    }
}

enum Path {
    case view1
    case view2
    case view3
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var path: [Path] = []
    func next() {
        path.append(path.count == 1 ? .view3 : .view2)
    }
}

struct View1: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel:ViewModel

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $viewModel.path) {
            VStack {
                Text("View 1").font(.largeTitle)
                Button("Goto 2") {
                    viewModel.next()
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: Path.self) { view in
                switch view {
                case .view2:
                    View2(viewModel: viewModel)
                case .view3:
                    View3()
                default:
                    EmptyView()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct View2: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("View 2").font(.largeTitle)
            Text("This should animate on the first time, but doesn't!")
            Text("Then if you navigate back and forth it animates fine!")
            Button("Goto 3") {
                viewModel.next()
            }
        }.padding()
    }
}

struct View3: View {

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("View 3").font(.largeTitle)
            Text("This should animate on")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I have the same...

Comment: In my case the problem dissapear if I use .fullScreenCover instead .sheet. But on my app I need a sheet and not an fullScreen...

Comment: Have you ever solved this?

Comment: Only by declaring the path as a @state in the view and then passing a binding back into the view model.

Comment: @drekka Ok then, it's still a good solution for now.

Answer (score 0):

try this approach, using a `@StateObject` in `ContentView` to "observe" the `ViewModel`, and pass it to `View1` such as `View1(viewModel: viewModel)`. Also importantly, moving the `NavigationStack` to the `ContentView` to make `View1` the root view, works for me.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showModal = false
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel() // <-- here

    var body: some View {
        Button("Show modal") {
            showModal = true
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showModal) {
            NavigationStack(path: $viewModel.path) {  // <-- here
                View1(viewModel: viewModel)  // <-- here
            }
        }
    }
}

struct View1: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("View 1").font(.largeTitle)
            Button("Goto 2") {
                viewModel.next()
            }
        }
        .navigationDestination(for: Path.self) { view in
            switch view {
            case .view2:
                View2(viewModel: viewModel)
            case .view3:
                View3()
            default:
                EmptyView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [known bug](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/728132) that you may be encountering. The solution is to apply an animation to the path with duration 0.

```
struct View1: View {

@ObservedObject var viewModel:ViewModel

var body: some View {
    NavigationStack(path: $viewModel.path.animation(.linear(duration: 0))) {
        // ...
```

FWIW I can't explain why this work around is needed but it does appear to resolve the issue for some people, maybe it will for you too.